# flatten to extract errors from object

Tags: lodash

How do I convert a list  like this into flattened array of error messages:

```
 "errors": {
    "Client": [
      "User client does not exist"
    ],
    "Password": [
      "User password has to have more than 6 characters",
      "The password and confirmation password do not match."
    ],
    "ConfirmPassword": [
      "Confirm Password has to have more than 6 characters"
    ]
  },
```

tried `var arr = _.toArray(data.errors);` but it doesnt flattent the objects that have multiple items in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lodash**

Use [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#values) (or [`_.toArray()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#toArray)) to get an array of error message arrays, and [`_.flatten()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatten) to convert to a single array.

```js
const errors = {"Client":["User client does not exist"],"Password":["User password has to have more than 6 characters","The password and confirmation password do not match."],"ConfirmPassword":["Confirm Password has to have more than 6 characters"]}

const result = _.flatten(_.values(errors))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Vanilla JS**

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array of error message arrays, and [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert to a single array

```js
const errors = {"Client":["User client does not exist"],"Password":["User password has to have more than 6 characters","The password and confirmation password do not match."],"ConfirmPassword":["Confirm Password has to have more than 6 characters"]}

const result = Object.values(errors).flat()

console.log(result)
```